# The argument type 'Future<void>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<void> Function()'

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a function

```
  Future<void> refresh({bool value = false}) async {
    changeUsers(await _service.loadUsers());
    if (value) return;
    ...
  }
```

in view I can use it the way

```
return RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: refresh,
    ...
```

but if I need to pass named parameter

```
return RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: refresh(value: true),
    ...
```

it gives the error

> The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter
> type 'Future Function()'.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onRefresh` on `RefreshIndicator` takes a function with the signature:

```dart
 Future<void> Function()
```

But when you provide `refresh(value: true)`, you are no longer providing a method of that signature but are instead calling your `refresh` function and provides the result of that call which ends up being `Future<void>`.

If you want to call your method with some specific arguments, you need to provide a function to `onRefresh` which does that. E.g.:

```dart
return RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: () => refresh(value: true),
...
```

We are here providing `() => refresh(value: true)` as anonymous function which calls `refresh(value: true)` and returns whatever that call might return which here is `Future<void>`. Therefore this provided method fits the specified signature for `onRefresh`.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error, you need to pass a function to the `onRefresh` parameter of `RefreshIndicator`. Currently, you are calling the `refresh` function and passing its result to `onRefresh`, which is causing the error.

To pass a named parameter to the `refresh function`, you can use a lambda function or an anonymous function.

```
return RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: () => refresh(value: true),
  ...
);
```